# detect audio tones near real time in c#

Tags: c#, signal-processing, real-time, goertzel-algorithm

I try to detect some audio signals(pure sine) in near real time. I know that I will get some latency. 
In the start I try to detect some tones of 10Khz in a duration of 75ms. That is achieved by a Goertzel filter. What is the prefered technique for that issue? I thought of making a little buffer that will always be detected by the Goertzel, but this sounds bad because I don't know when the the signal starts. Can you give me some help or idea ?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do something like I am trying to do here (please do contact me if you fix my inaccuracy issues though) [NAudio WaspiLoopback Goertzel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191860/naudio-waspiloopback-goertzel)

You can also take a look at: [Decoding DTMF from a WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092954/decoding-dtmf-from-a-wav-file) which have helped me a lot in getting something that can barely work, but it's a pretty good start.